# nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "source.blog.demo.com" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/blog.demo.com.conf:14

Tags: nginx

This is my nginx configuration:

```
upstream itw_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:2019 fail_timeout=3s;
}

proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/mpword levels=2:2 keys_zone=itw_cache:10m inactive=300d max_size=1g;
proxy_temp_path  /var/cache/nginx/tmp;

#
# the reverse proxy server as www
#
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name blog.demo.com;

    root       /opt/mpword/none;
    access_log /opt/mpword/log/www_access.log;
    error_log  /opt/mpword/log/www_error.log;

    client_max_body_size 2m;

    gzip            on;
    gzip_min_length 1024;
    gzip_buffers    4 8k;
    gzip_types      text/css application/x-javascript application/json;

    sendfile on;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        proxy_pass http://source.blog.demo.com;   // this is the line 14.
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        proxy_pass http://source.blog.demo.com;
    }

    location ~ /static/ {
        rewrite ^(.*) http://static.blog.demo.com$1 permanent;
    }

    location ~ /files/ {
        rewrite ^(.*) http://static.blog.demo.com$1 permanent;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://itw_upstream;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

#
# the source server that serves static files and uploaded files
#
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name source.blog.demo.com;

    root       /opt/mpword/../src/main/resources;
    access_log /opt/mpword/log/source_access.log;
    error_log  /opt/mpword/log/source_error.log;

    client_max_body_size 1m;

    gzip            on;
    gzip_min_length 1024;
    gzip_buffers    4 8k;
    gzip_types      text/css application/x-javascript application/json;

    sendfile on;

    location ~ /static/ {
    }

    location ~ /files/ {
        proxy_pass         http://itw_upstream;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_cache       itw_cache;
        proxy_cache_key   $uri;
        proxy_cache_valid 1d;

        expires    1d;
    }
}

#
# the simulated CDN server
#
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name static.blog.demo.com;

    access_log /opt/mpword/log/static_access.log;
    error_log  /opt/mpword/log/static_error.log;

    client_max_body_size 1m;

    gzip            on;
    gzip_min_length 1024;
    gzip_buffers    4 8k;
    gzip_types      text/css application/x-javascript application/json;

    sendfile on;

    location ~ /static/ {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  "http://blog.demo.com";
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST";

        proxy_pass         http://source.blog.demo.com;
        proxy_read_timeout 3s;
    }

    location ~ /files/ {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  "http://blog.demo.com";
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST";

        proxy_pass         http://source.blog.demo.com;
        proxy_read_timeout 3s;
    }
}
```

but when I run `nginx -t` I get error:

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "source.blog.demo.com" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/blog.demo.com.conf:14
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I didn't find the issue? how to solve it?

Comment: Like it is written: Nginx checks for upstream servers on proxy_pass directive. If it isn't reachable it does not start. Just guessing: The lower server is not running, while the proxy_pass directive is parsed in the upper on. So boot up two different or make sure the other one is first or use the well known solution for this proxy_pass problem.. (if you can't find, i'll post it again..)

Comment: please explain more. I don't understand `The lower server is not running, while the proxy_pass directive is parsed in the upper on. So boot up two different or make sure the other one is first or use the well known solution for this proxy_pass problem`

Answer (score 0):

This is your config:

```
server {

    server_name blog.demo.com;
    location = /favicon.ico {
        proxy_pass http://source.blog.demo.com;   # here you ask for a upstream server
    }
}
server {
    server_name source.blog.demo.com; # here you spin up the upstream server
}
```

Didn't test it, but I think the problem is, that nginx is looking for upstream servers given in `proxy_pass`. But the server `source.blog.demo.com` is not running at the time where the `proxy_pass` directive is loaded in the server `blog.demo.com`.

So 1.) make the second server the first one to spin up and the third the second. Finally run the `blog.demo.com`.

Or 2.) use the workaround preventing nginx checking for upstream servers in `proxy_pass`:

```
server {
  resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=30s; # or any other reachable DNS, e.g. 127.0.0.11 for docker 
  location = /favicon.ico {
        set $upstream_source source.blog.demo.com;
        proxy_pass http://$upstream_source/favicon.ico;   
    }
}
```